# What permissions are needed for Process.Kill()?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, permissions

Am I right in thinking that if a program is run as a user, and the program tries to kill another process started by the same user, this will succeed? And that the user would need to be in the Administrators group to kill any other process (including SYSTEM etc)?

Am I missing anything? Am I wrong/right?

Comment: Good inquiry, but have you tested your assumption? Generally, stackoverflow is for helping you solve problems that you can't solve on your own. Why not give this one a go on your own first?

Comment: You need a license to kill :)

Comment: It's possible that you'll need the SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE for some processes.

Comment: why don't you try it out and see?

Comment: What if you try and kill your own process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These articles [Permissions for Process.Kill()](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/225197-permissions-process-kill) and [Tip 13 : Kill a process using C#, from local to remote](http://weblogs.asp.net/stanleygu/archive/2010/03/31/tip-13-kill-a-process-from-local-to-remote.aspx) I'm sure will aid in testing your assumptions.

**** EDIT ****

The salient information in those articles is as follows (in case the links are down):

```
using System.Management;
using System.Management.Instrumentation;

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\RemoteMachineName\\root\\cimv2");
scope.Connect();

ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name='ProcessName'");
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

ManagementObjectCollection objectCollection = searcher.Get();
foreach(ManagementObject managementObject in objectCollection)
{
   managementObject.InvokeMethod("Terminate", null);
}
```